# Uninstalling TexLive issue on macOS Mojave

Tags: texlive

I realized I have quite hefty 13GB taken up by my 2018 and 2019 texlive versions and wanted a clean reinstall and a lightweight latex environment anyway. I read I can simply remove the folders under usr/local/texlive/XXXX year. I 'rm -rf' the 2018 folder without issues but got a spam of access denials when attempting the same for the 2019 folder.

Using an app (DaisyDisk - monitors storage on my mac) it warns me to delete it as "2019 is required by macOS and should not be removed". Is there any issue maybe from installing, can I just 'sudo rm -rf' it?

I am now uncertain if I should do that or if I can break something with that. If somebody can reassure me or explain me what I am dealing with that would be great.

Thanks already for your help everybody.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to tex.stackexchange.com. You should be able to use `sudo rm -rf 2019` from the parent directory with no harm done. In fact, this will be required if you installed TeX Live using the MacTeX package, as it installs with root ownership.

If you manually change ownership on the (e.g.) 2018 directory and its contents, or installed TeX Live via the standard UNIX installer script, you would not have to use `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you. I installed it online over the downloadable executable file. Okay thanks I will go ahead and sudo remove it then!